# Invert your code

Tags: code-golf, quine

## Challenge

Return the full contents of your program, but inverted. How do your invert something? Well,

**Letters**: Take the position of the letter in the alphabet, subtract from 26, and use the letter at that position and flip the case of the letter. E.g `A` becomes `z`, and `p` becomes `J`.

**Digits**: Subtract from 9. E.g `6` becomes `3` and `5` becomes `4`

**Brackets**: The brackets `(){}[]<>` become their corresponding closing/opening bracket. E.g `[` becomes `]` and `>` becomes `<`

**Other**

- `&` and `|` swap.
- ' ' [space] and '\n' [newline] swap.
- `£` and `$` swap, as do `€` and `¥`
- `¢` and `%` swap
- `_` and `-` swap
- `"` and `'` swap
- `?` and `!` swap
- `:` and `;` swap
- `/` and `\` swap
- `@` and `#` swap
- `~` and `` ` `` swap
- `,` and `.` swap
- `©` and `®` swap

All other characters become their Unicode inverse (subtract from 137,374). However, if the result is specified above, **you must replace it again with the replacement provided**. You only need to run a maximum of two replacements on each character, so no infinite loops.

## Rules

- Standard loopholes are disallowed

#### Good luck!

Comment: "the final product cannot be inverted any more" - but if you have one of the defined replacements (e.g. a letter) you can always invert it? So what do you really mean

Comment: Also, I'd highly recommend against that arbitrary "at least 4 characters in length" restriction

Comment: Sorry, that was an oversight on my part. Fixed.

Comment: The restriction on characters is just to avoid esoteric answers.

Comment: Sure... but I highly doubt there is (or ever will be) a language that can do this in 4 bytes, and even if so, the solution wouldn't be very interesting so it's not really a problem. 4 characters... maybe, if you count combining marks on the same character as a single character, but that doesn't matter since we count in bytes here

Comment: Removed char restrictions

Comment: Would have been much better if it were a little simpler, with fewer rules of inversion. But that's just my opinion (which I am not supposed to have).

Comment: Why did you accept my answer?.. :S It's way too soon, and it's not even the shortest..

Comment: [150 bytes](https://tio.run/##rYwxDoNADAS/kg8QhYJm3V0FSLQUWC5cXBEpAu6cxp@POf6QYqSZZs5cP0OEsfCNChkUTkQVmQoY5GCBNCmQVmyjbp7yWqcyg4RH2zT5mqc6F0IbqP/n8oj4Hef3fewW3TI8X/0F) but can't answer because on hold

Comment: [R, 190 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v9hGVz1BMcFGNzOvJCQ/tCTNwrrURrcUSIfke@aVWCcnlmgolmoUJBaXpBpoKNkr6SgaWwKxiY6SpoZevI6lhZmpibGhgbWVnY1iWWlJcVFBfl5OZnpaanJibLRuXVREWGhIkL@vj7enh7uba4KSpmZ0WmJySX6RBsJUoCMg5haDSSXr1LLEHKBsUXGqho5OsaYmUJdmrKY6hvj//wA); can't answer because on hold, but would like to see this challenge reopened.

Comment: [bash +tr, 104 bytes](https://tio.run/##Dcs7DsIwDADQPaewTFQnUuITWJUCDCyFga1LFD5St0rA1MRnD337e5Tv0vvvA5St84HBpDiXuCEhaR2lDREB48E7Dgasez@XFWrdmIuGOjMn1bb3@AIC8vvCqjIOLROICNhjul/y6TZN6Xo2vf8B)

Comment: Hi there! I see that this and your previous challenge have lots of comments beneath them asking for clarification or other improvements. Since you're rather new here, I would like to point out that we have a place for challenges to get refined before they get posted here. We call it [The Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1). I've liked both of your challenges so far, so I hope you continue to stay on PPCG and enjoy all the time you spend here. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Giuseppe. I've heard of/seen the sandbox before, but wasn't sure how to use it. Thanks though - I understand now.

Comment: Hi, I've edited your question to be a bit clearer. If there is anything I've done that you feel is not what you want, please correct me. In particular, I've removed the restrictions `Any reasonable language is fine`, `unless the \ is part of a control character`, the whole thing with the monkey emoji and the [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] tag. Hopefully this can be reopened and the solutions in the comments can be posted :)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 147 [bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7z209PEHv8PpMy3MbD68@POHwwsDMo/syXSqzTY2AIisOr1aPDcw8tOvQssOrQRqMLQ8vP7Q6NOJRwzwdvbBIryPtLkcXHF6aGXG46VHDwkgwCTSn/VHDIqPgQzuBFNCU5bFedLUuIdbr/38A)

```
0"D34çýεÐ.ïi9αëÐáQižiDyk52αèë']Qiº¦ë34ç39ç«UX„,.VYJćDŠåiXÂ‡YÂ‡ëÇ•2S¹•αçJ]J"D34çýεÐ.ïi9αëÐáQižiDyk52αèë']Qiº¦ë34ç39ç«UX„,.VYJćDŠåiXÂ‡YÂ‡ëÇ•2S¹•αçJ]J
```

Outputs:

```
9'x65,S0kSSxCQ47"[kS6560gd.,fcrxSdc7ir[r'x65,S0kSSxCQ47"[kS6560gd.,fcrxSdc7ir[r
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7z209PEHv8PpMy3MbD68@POHwwsDMo/syXSqzTY2AIisOr1aPDcw8tOvQssOrQRqMLQ8vP7Q6NOJRwzwdvbBIryPtLkcXHF6aGXG46VHDwkgwCTSn/VHDIqPgQzuBFNCU5V6xXvS27/9/AA)

If this can be done in 4 bytes without creating a new language doing this specific task I'd love to see it.. >.> Also, based on the characters to invert I almost have the feeling it's deliberately targeting 05AB1E.. xD Probably not the case, but almost all those characters are pretty frequently used builtins in 05AB1E..

### Explanation:

**[quine](/questions/tagged/quine)-part:**

The shortest [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) for 05AB1E is this one: `0"D34çý"D34çý` (**14 bytes**) [provided by *@OliverNi*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97899/52210). My answer uses a modified version of that quine by adding at the `...` here: `0"D34çý..."D34çý...`. A short explanation of this quine:

```python
0                 # Push a 0 to the stack (can be any digit)
 "D34çý"          # Push the string "D34çý" to the stack
        D         # Duplicate this string
         34ç      # Push 34 converted to an ASCII character to the stack: '"'
            ý     # Join everything on the stack (the 0 and both strings) by '"'
                  # (output the result implicitly)
```

**Challenge part:**

```python
ε                 # Map each character in the string to:
 Ð.ïi             #  If it's an integer:
     9α           #   Get it's absolute difference with 9
 ëÐáQi            #  Else-if it's a regular letter ([A-Za-z]):
      žiD         #   Push "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" twice
         yk       #   Get the index of the current character
           52α    #   Get the absolute difference with 52
              è   #   And index it into the string again
 ë']Qi           '#  Else-if it's a "]":
      º           #   Mirror it to "]["
       ¦          #   And remove the first character so just "[" remains
  34ç             #  Push '"'
     39ç          #  Push "'"
        «         #  Merge them together: `"'`
         UX       #  Save it in variable `X`
  „,.             #  Push ",."
     VY           #  Save it in variable `Y`
       J          #  Join the character, `"'` and ",." together
        ć         #  Extract the head (the character)
         DŠ       #  Duplicate and triple-swap, so the stack becomes char, `"',.`, char
 ë         åi     #  Else-if the character is in this string:
             XÂ   #   Push variable `X` and its reverse
               ‡  #   Transliterate the character
             YÂ   #   Push variable `Y` and its reverse
               ‡  #   Transliterate the character
 ë                #  Else:
  Ç               #   Convert the character to its unicode value
   •2S¹•          #   Push compressed integer 137374
        α         #   Take the absolute difference between the two
         ç        #   Convert it to a character again
          J       #   Join (workaround because very high unicode characters are wrapped
                  #         in a list for some reason)
]                 # Close all if-else statements and map
 J                # Join every mapped character together to a single string
                  # (and output the result implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•2S¹•` is `137374`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 142 bytes

```perl6
<my@a='a'..'z',@("<(|;~'@./£-".comb);my@b=@('Z'...'A'),@(Q'>)&:`"#,\=$_'.comb);"<$_>~~.EVAL".trans(pair((|@a,|@b),(|@b,|@a))).say>~~.EVAL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/98mt9Ih0VY9UV1PT71KXcdBQ8lGo8a6Tt1BT//DwoULDy3WVdJLzs9N0rQGKkyyddBQjwIq1VN3VNcEKg5Ut9NUs0pQUtaJsVWJV4eqVLJRiberq9NzDXP0UdIrKUrMK9YoSMws0tCocUjUqXFI0tQBspKArERNTU294sRKmOr//wE)

Avoids using most of the annoying to represent characters. I think this could be shorter